# Error 1054 on unused index in insertion

Tags: apache2, mysql-error-1054

**Unknown column 'timestamp' in 'where clause'**

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`name`, `username`, `password`, `email`, `mobile`, `passout`, `Batch`) 
VALUES ('ABC', '12141000', '4a7d1ed414474e4033ac29ccb8653d9b', 'user@domain.com', '88xxxxx', '2020', 'CS')
```

**DB:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(48) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `mobile` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `passout` char(4) NOT NULL,
  `Batch` enum('CS','EC','EE','others') NOT NULL,
  `examcode` int(11) NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=13 ;
```

**Data Insertion Code:**

Comment: It seems that error occurs somewhere else since the code you have posted does not consist 'where clause'

Comment: The error is somewhere else in your code. The query you show does not have a WHERE clause or a column names `timestamp`. Error messages normally have a line number and the filename where the error occured. Check those carefully

Comment: Their might be a another query that didn't end, so that you are getting such kind of error. You must look for your previous lines of code or need to share your code.

Comment: That i too  know, but this is the area which shows error...! error is shown in some core files of framework @RiggsFollly

Comment: Problem completely belongs to Mysql, if u hav apache, u can verify it@JitenderKakkar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry it was my mistake, my **`trigger`** was **on** which calls the column name `'timestamp'`..
visibly there is no where clause which made me confused...